# How to Fix VS C# calling 64-bit COM throws An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException'

Tags: c#, delphi, com

I have a COM DLL compiled in both 32-bit and 64-bit under Delphi Berlin Update 2. And it has no problems at all when calling the COM in both 32-bit and 64-bit VBScript (System\cscript.exe for 64-bit and SysWOW64\cscript.exe for 32-bit [see this post](https://helloacm.com/make-sure-run-script-under-32-bit-cscript-exe-or-wscript-exe-when-32-bit-com-object-is-needed/) for more details), like this:

```
set rpm = CreateObject("RPMLib.RadioTracer")
set rpu = CreateObject("RPMLib.Utility")
rpm.SomeMethod();
rpu.SomeMethod();
```

That means that I have registered both 32-bit and 64-bit successfully like this:

```
regsvr32 RPMLib.dll
```

The delphi compiler compiles the same source code into two versions. So that basically, the 32-bit and 64-bit 's GUID are the same. I have copied below the GUIDs from the _TLB.pas file

```
LIBID_RPMLib: TGUID = '{D6A7108C-E217-4012-9BAA-E82693CE080C}';
IID_IUtility: TGUID = '{F9372AF6-6DAB-4F3F-B017-73FA147CF563}';
CLASS_Utility: TGUID = '{B1694005-EF15-4ED8-9368-6657C6FE3658}';
IID_IRadioTracer: TGUID = '{0DD935C7-ED78-4ACB-94CE-9981359BBE36}';
CLASS_RadioTracer: TGUID = '{175BB24D-598C-4019-AD29-63FC0A47B11F}';
IID_CallBackFuncs: TGUID = '{05E82013-E197-4C0E-B2C4-504226CC1298}';
```

I have created a C# Console Application (Visual Studio 2015), add the COM Reference and put the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using RPMLib;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var rpu = new Utility();            
            Console.WriteLine(rpu.Author);
            var rpm = new RadioTracer();
            Console.WriteLine(rpm.Author);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

It works if the targeted platform is x86. However, when I switch to x64, it throws this error (and very **surprisingly** only throws error when creating the RadioTracer class but not the other one e.g. Utility class):

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in ConsoleApplication2.exe
>   Additional information: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'RPMLib.RadioTracer'. This
>   operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component
>   for the interface with IID '{0DD935C7-ED78-4ACB-94CE-9981359BBE36}'
>   failed due to the following error: Unspecified error (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL)).

The RPMLib.dll has basically exported two Objects so you can create *RadioTracer()* and *Utility()*

And from the Delphi source code I can see they are created in-process:

```
TAutoObjectFactory.Create(ComServer, TUtility, Class_Utility, ciMultiInstance,
  tmApartment);
TAutoObjectFactory.Create(ComServer, TRadioTracer, Class_RadioTracer,
  ciMultiInstance, tmApartment);
```

Finally, here are some screenshots, any hints?

[image]

[image]

[image]

and here is the RadioTracer.cs

```
// Decompiled with JetBrains decompiler
// Type: RPMLib.RadioTracer
// Assembly: Interop.RPMLib64, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
// MVID: FDE1BB7D-808A-44B6-BE39-4DB3EFA8395B
// Assembly location: c:\RPMLib_Integration_Tests\TestData\Interop.RPMLib64.dll

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace RPMLib
{
  [Guid("0DD935C7-ED78-4ACB-94CE-9981359BBE36")]
  [CoClass(typeof (RadioTracerClass))]
  [ComImport]
  public interface RadioTracer : IRadioTracer
  {
  }
}
```

and the Utility.cs

```
// Decompiled with JetBrains decompiler
// Type: RPMLib.Utility
// Assembly: Interop.RPMLib64, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
// MVID: FDE1BB7D-808A-44B6-BE39-4DB3EFA8395B
// Assembly location: c:\RPMLib_Integration_Tests\TestData\Interop.RPMLib64.dll

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace RPMLib
{
  [CoClass(typeof (UtilityClass))]
  [Guid("F9372AF6-6DAB-4F3F-B017-73FA147CF563")]
  [ComImport]
  public interface Utility : IUtility
  {
  }
}
```

Other experiments:
I have removed 32-bit registration *regsvr32 /u RPMLib.dll* and problem still occurs
I have tried to add the 32-bit and 64-bit *interop.RPMLib.dll* to the project reference instead of choosing the COM dll itself, and it doesn't help.

Comment: thanks.  re-edited.

Comment: Do you have source of RPMLib.dll? Could you provide mininal compilable version of it that reproduces the issue?